# Filling available space while aligning to parent

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

The LinearLayout sticks to the bottom of the RelativeLayout, but has fixed height(wrap_content of its child - the button).

I would like the LinearLayout to have as much available space as its possible(because ListView can have 0 or 1000 elements), but also ensure, that the button will be still visible when ListView has a lot of elements.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
</ListView>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" >
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: explain little bit more.

Comment: What isn't working with the layout you have?

Comment: Current behaviour is bad? Or? Add here screenshot.

Comment: The height of the LinearLayout is limited to the height of a button. I want this LinearLayout to have as much height as possible, not only the amount needed for the button.

Comment: And what about the listview height?

Comment: The ListView has to take as much height as possible, BUT the button has to be always visible.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following and see if it works:

1. Change RelativeLayout to LinearLayout, and add android:orientation="vertical"
2. Assign different layout weight to "listview1" and "linear". For listview1, use android:layout_weight="1". For "linear", use android:layout_weight="2"

Hope it helps.